# php print script without printing print button

Tags: php, printing

hi i have a print script to print the page

```
$print9 ='<script>
function printpage()
  {
  window.print()
  }
</script>
    </head>
    <body><input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printpage()">

    </body>

    </html></div>
    ';

echo $print9;
```

it works perfectly but it also print the print button in hardcopy and dnt want to print the print button
how can i do this i have also search but i am not able to understand there answers.

Comment: EDIT: At least now it makes a bit more sense. o.o''

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question (with proper puncutation, perhaps)? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I think he means the button itself gets printed in the printed copy.

Comment: yes i want not to print print button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't just:

```
<script>window.print()</script>
```

Or if you want to print onclick but hide the button:

```
@media print {
  /* style sheet for print goes here */
  .hide-from-printer{  display:none; }
}
```

Now any elements with this class will not be visible when printed, so just apply it to the button:

```
<input class="hide-from-printer" type="button" value="Print" onclick="printpage()">
```

Comment: doesn't seem useful if he wants it to print when the button is clicked instead of on page load

Comment: it works for me but it can be possible that it will not print directly  only after clicking a link or button

Comment: So use @Joucks answer, set styles for print devices

Comment: how can i use @media print i never used this

Comment: This the exactly what i want. thanks ( i have a question that why the marked my question as minus)

Comment: Someone have downvoted it.. You should allways try to make your questions as more complete, clean and clear as posible. good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS and a `@media print` rule to hide your button for the "print" media.

Answer (score 2):

Simple !

```
<script>window.print()</script>
```